# Simple fetching of data throws error - Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to do a simple fetching from a dummy page. When I run the code I get the error below in the debugger and no output in the console like I would like

```
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Main() {

useEffect(() => {
const fetchTodos = async () => {
  await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/products/1").then((res) =>
     console.log(res.json())
  );
};

fetchTodos();
}, []);

return <div>Fetch Dummy</div>;
```

layout.jsx:

```
 export default function RootLayout() {
 return (
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Digital</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <Main></Main>
  </body>
 </html>
 );
}
```

> caught SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
> at JSON.parse ()
> at parseModel (webpack-internal:///
>
> The above error occurred in the ServerRoot component:

Answer (score 0):

The operation `res.json()` is async so your console.log will only receive a promise. You need to await it or use a callback.

Also, don't mix async/await with callbacks. Choose one or the other. For example using async:

```
const res = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/products/1");
const data = await res.json();
console.log(data)
```

This outputs

```
{id: 1, title: 'iPhone 9', description: 'An apple mobile which is nothing like apple', price: 549, discountPercentage: 12.96, …}
```